# SQL anagram efficiency and logic?

Tags: sql, performance, logic

I have an SQL db with about 200,000 words.  I need a query which I will be able to solve an anagram kind of.  The difference is that I need all the possible words that could be made with the input characters. For example, if you input **ofdg**, it should output the words: **do**, **go**, and **dog**.  Can you estimate the amount of time a query like this would take.  How can I make it faster and more efficient?  Also, in general how long does it take SQL to parse a 200000 row database.

Comment: What does your schema look like? What have you tried?  This smells like a homework assignment to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve this problem, the first thing you need to do is reduce every word to what Scrabble players call an alphagram. That is, all the letters in the word but in alphabetical order. So `do`, `go` and `dog` make `do`, `go` and `dgo`. Of course, any given alphagram may correspond to more than one word, so, for example, alphagram `dgo` corresponds to both the words `dog` and `god`.

The next thing you need to do is construct a table with a key *alphagram-sequence number* and a single attribute field *word*.

Word lists tend to be static. For example, the two Scrabble word lists in the English-speaking world change about every 5 years of so. So you construct this lookup table beforehand. Performance is *O*( *n* ) and it is a sunk cost. That is, you do it once and store it, so it is not counted against the cost of the query. You *have* to do this beforehand. It makes absolutely no sense to build such an index on the fly every time a query comes in.

You may be wondering "What is all this about Scrabble?" The answer is that your figure of 200,000 words falls neatly between the two approved tournament word lists in the English-speaking world. The US National Scrabble Association's *Official Tournament and Club Word List* (2006) contains 178,691 words, and the international list, maintained by the World English Scrabble Players' Association, contains 246,691.

When you get a query you reduce the supplied word to a bunch of alphagrams. Input `odfg` makes alphagrams `od` `fo` `go` `df` `dg` `fg` `dfo` `dgo` `fgo` `dfg` `dfgo` (which is a pretty programming problem in pure SQL, so I have to assume there is a PHP or Python or JavaScript front-end that will do that for you). Then you do the lookup in the database. The cost of each query should be approximately *O*(log2 *n*), in other words pretty damn immediate. That sort of query is what relational databases are good at.

BTW, your example output is poor. Alphagram `dfgo` with what Scrabble players call 'build' (all possible subsets) makes `do` `od` `of` `go` `dog` `god` `fog`.

(I hate to have to do this rigmarole, but Hasbro's lawyers are touchy, so: *Scrabble is a registered trademark owned in the USA by Hasbro, Inc.; in Canada by Hasbro Canada Corporation; and throughout the rest of the world by J. W. Spear & Sons, a Mattel Company.*)

Comment: This is a fantastic explanation Boar Gules I really appreciate the help I have never gotten such an in depth answer great work thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the number of possible letter combination in a word of length `n` is `n!`. Apparently you have a few more options as you want the shorter words as well, but that does not change that much the general `O(n!)` relationship. So a simple algorithm trying all combinations and looking the up in the database will have that as complexity.

Making the algorithm more efficient is apparently to reduce the search space - for which there are a few options.

How long it takes to look up a 200.000 row table depends on what kind of data is stored in there, in what format and what indexes you have on that table.